# array type of question

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out a way to make a small "table" style system in php for about 10 data rows.  Because it requires constant editing, I want to replace my mysql system for something in php directly.

The data is 10 rows of:

```
id
first name
last name
```

I give the php file the id and want to pull out the first name and last name.

I tried using a associative array, but that turned into a coding mess as my syntax was all over the place.

How can I set this one up properly so i can edit the data easily in a single place and get first and last name of a row by its $id?

edit - example:

```
id fname lname
1  john  ter
2  mark  laken
3  peter lars
4  vlad  morch
```

Basically, how do I set that info above up in php such that I can add new rows without too much trouble and the code will still work, and such that it is possible to output the fname and lname from a $_GET of an id value...

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Show your code or at least show an example so that we can know what are you trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not understanding why you wouldn't want to store constantly changing data in the database, but here is how I would hardcode it:

```
$data = array(
  'id01' => array(
    'firstName' => 'Eric',
    'lastName' => 'Smith',
  ),
  'id02' => array(
    'firstName' => 'John',
    'lastName' => 'Turner',
  ),
  ...
);
```

If you were returning this data in an ajax call I'd do it along these line

```
echo json_encode($data[$id]);
```

Of course you should also test if the value in $id is in your data array.

Comment: I assumed from your question that you will edit the php file directly to change the data, if this isn't the case (for example if you want to edit the fields on a form in a webpage), then you would need to put the data in a file or a database, php scripts are not persistent.

Comment: Sorry, I just saw the json_encode part IS in php format.  I tried $data[$id][firstName] and comfirmed working and all.  Cheers Ericson.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure I understand what you're looking for, but if you want to be able to edit something inline and save it on form input blur, you will have to look beyond PHP and into an AJAX solution. You will likely still want to back this with a database as PHP scripts don't have a continuous runtime, so you can't read all the data into memory and change it directly in memory through user interaction. So what you'll do is read all the data from the DB into a form, then using a little ajax, you will be able to save the form data back to the database everytime a value is changed.